# QListWidget, rename items with user input

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have contextmenu to a `listWidget` with delete and rename item. For delete, I used `RemoveRow`. But, I can't rename with user-input. How can I replace this line `item.setText('new_name')` by an action allow my change name by user

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItems('apple orange lemon'.split())
        self.listWidget.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu and
            source is self.listWidget):
            menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
            Delete = menu.addAction('Delete')
            Rename = menu.addAction('Rename')
            #action = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
            action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())) #when inside self
            if action == Delete:
                item = source.itemAt(event.pos())
                source.model().removeRow(source.currentRow())
            elif action == Rename:
                item = source.itemAt(event.pos())
                #
                item.setText('new')
                "How can I rename by user input, not by setText??"
                
            return True
        return super(Dialog, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Dialog()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: first use some widget in window to ask for this name or use some Dialog window for this. And when you get text from user then you can use `setText()` to change name. See [QInputDialog](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-input-dialog/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QInputDialog.getText()` to ask for new text and use it with `setText()`.

```
elif action == Rename:

    text, okPressed = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, "New name","New name:")
    
    if okPressed and text != '':
        item = source.itemAt(event.pos())
        item.setText(text)
```

You can even copy text from list to `QInputDialog` so user can edit it.

```
elif action == Rename:

    item = source.itemAt(event.pos())

    text, okPressed = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, "New name","New name:", text=item.text())
    
    if okPressed and text != '':
        item.setText(text)
```

---

Full working code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItems('apple orange lemon'.split())
        self.listWidget.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu and
            source is self.listWidget):
            menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
            Delete = menu.addAction('Delete')
            Rename = menu.addAction('Rename')
            #action = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
            action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())) #when inside self
            if action == Delete:
                item = source.itemAt(event.pos())
                source.model().removeRow(source.currentRow())
            elif action == Rename:

                item = source.itemAt(event.pos())

                text, okPressed = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, "New name","New name:", text=item.text())
    
                if okPressed and text != '':
                     item.setText(text)
                
            return True
        return super(Dialog, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Dialog()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution